# Suppressing the automatic newline in Print

Tags: evaluation

Print automatically generates a newline at the end of the expression that is being printed.  How do you suppress this automatic newline?

Comment: So `Print /@ {1, 2, 3};` should generate `123` below/in messages notebook? What about prints in future, should they append this `123`?

Comment: assemble what you want to print as a single expression first.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this problem is to write strings to the standard output directly. For instance,

```
WriteString[$Output, "aaa"];
WriteString[$Output, "bbb"];
```

Comment: It is not what `Print` does if one has `PrintToConsole` settings on.